Is there a relationship between thr increasing number of airliners flying over 11000 metres and the number of problematic air pocket events?
I saw many news about the death of a passenger on Singapore Airlines flight. They say that the accident was caused by a turbulence. But judging from the description of what happened I thought about an air pocket. I was surprised when I saw that the plane was flying so high, I still associate the airliner with a plane that flies at a altitude slightly above 10000 metres.
I had a look on Flight Radar, I chose some random long range flights and I saw that most of them were travelling above 11000 metres and some above 12000 metres. It seems that the average travelling altitude is increasing. Is it going to have an impact on the number of events of planes dropping by a thousand metres or more due to air pockets during the flight?

https://skybrary.aero/articles/clear-air-turbulence-cat

"Air pocket" and turbulence mean the same thing.

Airliner cruise altitude is not increasing, at least not in the past forty years.

Please cite your source that “… the average travelling height is increasing.”

FWIW, the cause of death is suspected to be a heart attack:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Airlines_Flight_321  It could have been influenced by stress as a result of turbulence, but turbulence was not the direct cause of death.

Boeing models, for example, have had service ceilings in the low 40kft range for decades now.  That said, obviously, over the years the number of revenue passenger miles above (for example) 35kft has increased considerably. To me an interesting statistic would be number of injuries (or deaths) attributed to turbulence per revenue passenger mile, by year.

In short
Aircraft cruise altitude is linked to the tropopause altitude, which rises with climate change, about 1 000 ft in 50 years.
Turbulence events are not linked to this change in altitude but are still linked to climate change. Their rate may double or triple in the coming years, and it is a certainty their intensity will increase.
This is the general trend for many atmospheric events. High inertia oceans warm, leading to more evaporation and more water in air, thus more energy is stored everywhere, thus stronger winds are generated.
Some more details below if you're interested.

Troposphere and tropopause
Atmosphere temperature starts at about 15°C at sea level and continuously decreases at the rate of 1°C per 180 m while moving away from the warmer Earth, until reaching -50 to -65°C at an altitude of about 8 to 17 km (depending on latitude and month).
This layer of the atmosphere where temperature decreases is called the troposphere and its upper limit the tropopause. For a latitude of 45° the tropopause altitude is about 10-11 km
Tropopause rise

It seems that the average traveling altitude is increasing.

This increasing cruise altitude is likely linked to the increasing altitude of the tropopause. Aircraft and their engines are optimized for an altitude  close to the tropopause where the most favorable combination of temperature, density and pressure is found.
The mean atmosphere temperature started increasing circa 1920:

Source. Data source: WMO/AFP. Full size image.
This moderate change inflated a little bit the troposphere, inducing a tropopause rise by 50-60 m (160 ft) per decade. Over the last 50 years the tropopause altitude increased by about 250-300 m (820-980 ft).
Flight levels
Cruising aircraft fly at "levels", which are hundreds of feet, e.g. FL360 is 360 x 100 ft = 36 000 ft.
Aircraft that were optimized for flight level FL340 (10 360 m) in the 70s must now fly at FL350 (10 670 m) to get the same conditions.
Similarly cruising at FL350 (10 670 m) has evolve to cruising at FL 360 (11 970 m), etc, there is a general rise of 1 000 ft or +10 in FL unit.
Clear air turbulence
Turbulence is another word for wind. Given the aircraft own motion, the most problematic impact is from a vertical wind, they should be avoided. Many turbulence areas, often located between the ground and cumulonimbus clouds, can be remotely detected by airborne weather radars and by-passed.
Clear air turbulence (CAT) is another type of turbulence, linked to jet streams, occurring mostly close to the tropopause. It cannot be detected by radars and is the most frequent cause of a sudden, sometimes spectacular, vertical aircraft motion (an obvious reason to have the seatbelt fastened in cruise).
CAT events dynamics

Is it going to have an impact on the number of events of planes dropping by a thousand metres or more due to air pockets during the flight?

The number of CAT has increased, and CAT events are more intense. The intensity is expected to continue to increase, and it can pose an actual threat to commercial aviation in the long term.
According to this study, about CAT over North Atlantic:

Severe-or-greater CAT increased the most, becoming 55% more frequent in 2020 than 1979.

This is a bit less over the US (41%). The trend is not good either:

Turbulence strong enough to pose an injury risk could double or triple in frequency.


Number of injuries (or deaths) attributed to turbulence per revenue passenger mile, by year? Anybody? RPM data is not hard to come by but need help on the other.

Was there some reference to 1920 and trend in that link you provided?

@ThomasPerry: This is a link to the diagram. The baseline for the temperature anomaly is the mean of years 1881-1900, the pre-industrial era where the global temperature (sea and land) was relatively constant. The anomaly figures are the difference with the baseline. You can see on the first diagram, the increase indeed starts in 1920, and you can read more on the pre-industrial reference in What is a pre-industrial climate.

Nonetheless, interesting...
